# Diplomacy question involving a convoy

Tags: diplomacy

An army is being convoyed, with a force of 2, into a coastal region where there is an opposing fleet.
The opposing fleet(moving) is attempting to dislodge the convoy, with a force of 2.
The convoying fleet is supported adequately so that it is not dislodged.
Do the units bounce or does the army land successfully?

Answer (score 1):

If the convoy is not dislodged, the army can use it as long as it has enough strength to enter the area.

Answer (score 1):

The convoyed army lands successfully, dislodging the fleet, provided this description accurately resembles the problem:

Germany:
***A DEN*** - BEL convoyed by **F NOR S**
**A HOL** sup **A DEN** - BEL
**F NWY** sup **F NOR S** standing

France:
***F BEL*** - North Sea
**F ENG C** sup **F BEL** - NOR S

Since the convoying fleet is not dislodged, and the convoyed army arrives with greater force than the fleet defends with, the convoy is successful and **F BEL** is dislodged.

Comment: The part at the bottom is incorrect. If A BUR S BEL and F BEL-NTH are both ordered, then the support order for BUR is invalid since BEL is moving. So there is no change to the adjudication in this case.